# UITableview displays only 1 section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been trying to using UITableView nested with collectionView. The problem is the numberOfSections returns more than 1 has value but still the UITableView displays only 1 section. I have used the below code to implement. How to fix this issue.

```swift
class HomeTableVC: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    }

    extension HomeTableVC : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 240
    }
 
     func nummberOfSetions(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if tabType == 0 {
            return (ThemeModel?.category.count)!
        } else if tabType == 5 {
            return (WallpaperModel?.category.count)!
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if tabType == 0 {
            return ThemeModel?.category[section] // returns 2
        } else if tabType == 5 {
            return WallpaperModel?.category[section]
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        cell.colletionview.tag = indexPath.section
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.97, green: 0.97, blue: 0.97, alpha: 1.00)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
nummberOfSetions
```

To

```
numberOfSections
```